# Отрисовка линии (вменяемое описание внутри вопроса).

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Допустим делается нечто на вроде фамильного дерева. Т.е. блоки соединенные связями. Связи изображаются простыми линиями.
1) Как реализовать автоматическую отрисовку линий. (На странице заданы блоки, а связи рендерятся в зависимости от блоков.)
2) Как перерисовывать связи, если блоки можно перетаскивать?

Честно, даже не знаю с чего начинать. Для самого простого примера, возьмем, что есть 2 квадратных div'a. Нужно чтобы их центры соединялись линией. Причем она была под div'ами.

Comment: Кхм, рисовать линии вам поможет canvas. 

1 - смоделировать, как будет работать связь и по ней написать скрипт соответственно. 

2 - вытекает из пункта 1. Просто заново рисуете линию.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov, думаю, что вам пригодиться плагин [Arrows-and-boxes](http://www.headjump.de/article/arrows-and-boxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще использовать в таком случае Canvas:) В Jquery можно вычислять координаты относительно родителя:) Потом с этими координатами можно уже работать в Canvas'е, там есть функции рисования линии.. Даже плавную линию можешь нарисовать:) При перетаскивания блока нужно делать пересчитывания:) На самом деле это теорически не так трудно:) Может показаться нудно:)